# Why is facebook's html wrapped inside a table mobile login page?

Tags: html, facebook

Why is Facebook's HTML wrapped inside a table mobile login page ?
Even more intriguing, inside the table there is a single tbody with a single tr with a single td.

https://m.facebook.com/ (login page)

Comment: This isn't a coding question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem as outlined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference between tables and other html elements is: They don't get rendered at all before the whole content is completely loaded. By using this trick, the authors made sure the page renders only the way as they intended and does not display only a part of the elements there.

Of course, they targeted especially mobile connections which could break while loading the page or could be terribly slow so you might start using the page although it's not loaded completely yet.

Comment: Interesting...nice trick to have up the sleeve

Comment: does https make this technique redundant ? I learned that , to decode something you need all of the content loaded anyway, right ?

Comment: Not quite. In https, the content encryption is performed using a symmetric encryption algorithm such as AES. The asymmetric part of https is there only for authenticatin and to encrypt the connection until the handshake is done, which includes negotiating a symmetric key. AES is a so-called block-cipher. That means, the content is encrypted and decrypted block-wise (such as blocks of 128bytes). So not the whole content needs to be transferred, but always a block of 128 bytes has been completely transferred, it is going to be decrypted.

Comment: may this change with new tls proposals such as TLS 1.3  with small data < 1 KB ?

Comment: I don't see why it should. To prevent the page from being partially rendered, you would need to encrypt _all_ the contents together, send it to the client which is not able to decrypt it before _everything_ has been received. The nature of HTML, however, is that resources are loaded asynchronously, i.e. images are loaded later, css can be loaded later on, and so the basic html content is available although not fully loaded. But each resource is loaded using a new request and a new response which _must_ be encrypted separately (otherwise the client would not know what image to request)...